# How to disable traffic alert messages which come as flash sms from carrier?

Tags: carriers

I get this alert message [(screenshot from my phone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy0oU.jpg) from my carrier after using the internet for sometime. The problem is that I get numerous messages (20+) like this when my phone is idle. I guess some apps are syncing in the background. The phone is unusable till I hit OK on all the alert boxes. Is there a way (or an app) to make sure that I do not see these messages.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a special kind of SMS message, sometimes called "flash SMS", that shows up instantaneously on the phones screen. I don't think that there is an option to block these messages and even if it would be possible I wouldn't encourage you to do so, because you could maybe miss some other important information.

**I think the best approach would be to ask your carrier from disabling these messages for your number. I am sure that they are able and happy to do so.**

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the term "flash SMS". I found a solution by googling it. My argument for disabling it is this - what if I need to make an emergency call? I might not have time to keep hitting the OK buttons on all those messages. Anyway the solution that worked for me can be found here http://www.digitalgupshup.com/how-to-stop-block-flash-service-sms-of-vodafone-india/

Comment: @pkdevil You should post how you disabled flash-sms as answer to help others with this issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Balance Update / USSD blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melkote.quietbalance)

You can install this app to block the Flash messages

This Does not support Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your carrier where they send the last data usage details whenever a data connection session ends. It is not possible to disable it unless the network provider disables it.

However, you can try this small workaround by going to `Messaging`, selecting `Settings` in options, and disabling `Cell Broadcast` settings.

Thanks